# Eclipse, Oracle, no Middleware folder

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic, middleware

Could you explain me how to install new Oracle WebLogic? 
I installed Middleware  WebLogic Server 12.2.1. 
That adds a lot of options to my eclipse but I can't set "WebLogic home" because   "Middleware" folder doesn't exist.